# configurate quartz by ihm

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Hi I would like that the user of my application choose an expression via the IHM and to configure one service in fact I configure quartz every hour it works well but when I tried to let the user configure the time of execution of the job number of thing is passed, I used this code:

```
public void collectorCronScheduling(String expression) {
    try {
        triggerBean.setCronExpression(expression);
        triggerBean.validate();
        System.out.println("cron expression modifiée");
        schedulerFactoryBean.start();
        System.out.println("scheduler started");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public CronTriggerBean getTriggerBean() {
    return triggerBean;
}

public void setTriggerBean(CronTriggerBean triggerBean) {
    this.triggerBean = triggerBean;
}

public SchedulerFactoryBean getSchedulerFactoryBean() {
    return schedulerFactoryBean;
}

public void setSchedulerFactoryBean(
        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean) {
    this.schedulerFactoryBean = schedulerFactoryBean;
}
```

this is the applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="collectorTicketServiceImplJob"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="collectorTicketServiceImpl" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="ExtractTicketFromMail" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="collectorTicketServiceImplTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

        <property name="jobDetail" ref="collectorTicketServiceImplJob" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/30 * * * ?" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="collectorTicketServiceImplTriggerSchedular"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">

        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="collectorTicketServiceImplTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: What is IHM? User interface? And what problem occurs when you try to "let the user configure the time of execution"? Do you get a stack trace you can share? Or can you explain the unexpected behavior?

Comment: yes IHM is user interface, nothing is passed when the user uses expression, i know that i should change the application context but i don't know how the service is executed every 30 minutes like it is mentionned in the applicationContext but i would like to execute it every time mentionned by the user